# How to make angular-material tabs transparent?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Angular material allows us to configure themes to give a custom colour to `<md-tabs>`, or for that matter any of it's components.

Is there any way I can make these tabs look transparent so that I can view the background image?

Applying an inline style doesn't help.

Comment: can you paste the html code here? or JSFIDDLE would be good.

Comment: I'll try to create a fiddle for this when I get time. But the issue is very simple to understand, I guess, without a fiddle. My requirement is just transparent `md-tabs`. 
Official demo : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

Comment: you want to add background image to whole `<md-tabs>` ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/faYrbOXUiZGgoVQUfBeP?p=preview
This is the plunker. For some reason angular-material isn't working. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean? [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/dpvaRr?editors=1100)

CSS

```
#background {
  background-image: url("http://images.photowall.com/products/44352/rural-forest?h=700&q=92");
  height: 100%;
}

.tabsdemoDynamicHeight md-content md-tabs {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

#myTabs md-tabs-wrapper {
  background: transparent;
}

#myTabs md-tab-content {
  background: white
}
```

Markup

```
<md-tabs id="myTabs" md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
```

Comment: Exactly ! I made another small change to make tab's content also transparent and that is it ! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @SohanShirodkar Glad to help. I wasn't sure if you wanted everything transparent so I deliberately made the content white.